# How to separate a large file based on a key and store the file in separate dictionaries using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, file

Being new to python I am trying to figure out how a sample file in below format could be separated into multiple parts and store it in a separate dictionary based on the value associate with the key "type".Can anybody share some inputs on this. Thanks.

```
[
{"type": "A", "verb": "NEW", "key": "96f55c7d8f42", "event_time": "2017-01-06:12:46:46.384Z", "last_name": "Smith", "adr_city": "Middletown", "adr_state": "AK"},
{"type": "B", "verb": "NEW", "key": "ac05e815502f", "event_time": "2017-01-06:12:45:52.041Z", "customer_id": "96f55c7d8f42", "tags": {"some key": "some value"}},
{"type": "C", "verb": "UPLOAD", "key": "d8ede43b1d9f", "event_time": "2017-01-06:12:47:12.344Z", "customer_id": "96f55c7d8f42", "camera_make": "Canon", "camera_model": "EOS 80D"},
{"type": "D", "verb": "NEW", "key": "68d84e5d1a43", "event_time": "2017-01-06:12:55:55.555Z", "customer_id": "96f55c7d8f42", "total_amount": "12.34 USD"}
]
~
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you file is `data.txt`, try this:

```
import json

with open('data.txt') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for row in data:
    print("Type: " + row['type'])
    print(row)
    print()
```

Comment: I would like to store the data in separate data structures and use it in my following functions that I would be applying on these data structures.

Comment: Can you show this following code then? Edit the original post.

Comment: I still need to write it but the question I am facing with is in storing data into separate dictionaries based on type attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably with a dictionary of dictionaries.

Write an iterator that reads each line, and uses `ujson` to parse the text into a `dict`. Then `pop` the value you want to use as a key, and return both parts.

```
 import ujson

 def read_lines(file_path):
     with open(file_path, 'r') as fh:
         for line in fh:
             dictionary = ujson.loads(line)
             key = dictionary.pop('key')
             yield key, dictionary


dictionaries = dict()
for key, value in read_lines(r"/foo/bar/file.txt"):
    dictionaries[key] = value
```